# nginx rewrite file inside virtual directory

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

My folder structure is as follows
I have a folder named `docs` inside of which I have 2 files:
`all_docs.php` and `level.php`

all_docs has 2 parameters and I have this rewrite rule:

```
rewrite ^/doc-([^/]*)-([^/]*)/?$ /doc/all_docs.php?title=$1&lang=$2 last;
```

Which makes makes possible for an url like

```
all_docs.php?title=fashion&lang=en
```

to look like:

```
/doc-fashion-en/
```

The problem is that I also want to access level.php inside doc folder but
After the rewrite I cannot because nginx requests:

`/doc-fashion-en/level.php` which doesn't exist

I have tried 
rewrite ^/doc-([^/]*)-([^/]*)/level.php /doc/level.php?$args;

without success, level.php has some get parameters that need to be passed
that's why I used $args.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How should the request for `level.php` look? `/doc-title-lang/level.php` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, uncluding parameters like level.php?lang=us&volume=4
etc

Answer (score 0):

These rewrite rules should work for you:

```
rewrite ^/doc-([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /doc/all_docs.php?title=$1&lang=$2 last;
rewrite ^/doc-[^/]+-[^/]+/level.php(.*)$ /doc/level.php$1 last;
```

Consider using `+` instead of `*` when you are sure there should be at least one symbol. In fact, `^/doc-([^/]*)-([^/]*)/?$` matches `/doc--`. Not sure that is intented.